# Looping though $_POST. How to stop when looping has finished?

Tags: php, function, oop, return

I want this function to return false when for each statement has stopped looping. And true if it's not empty.

```
function check_empty($post_array){
        $items_in_array = count($post_array); //array length
        echo $items_in_array;
        foreach($post_array as $key=>$value){
            if(empty($value)){
                echo $key . " field cannot be left empty" . "</br>";
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Note: if i return false inside foreach it will stop right on first iteration i want it to complete iteration and only stop when it has iterated over  all the values in that array($post_array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i return false inside foreach it will stop right on first iteration i want it to complete iteration and only stop when it has iterated over all the values

So an empty value would be considered an “error” of some sort, and one such error should be enough to make the function return false?

```
function check_empty($post_array){
    $no_empty_fields = true;
    foreach($post_array as $key=>$value){
        if(empty($value)){
            $no_empty_fields = false;
            // plus whatever additional handling you need here
        }
    }
    return $no_empty_fields;
}
```

Comment: or, simply use break to stop that iteration and move on to the next one :-?

Comment: Using `break` alone does not change the overall return value of the function, and that seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: break will not stop the loop from iterating all the results. And if the function does NOT return false, then it's only logical that it returns true. A statement is either true or false... cannot be maybe :) although that would be a major breakthrough in programming. so why overload the function with unnecessary flags? I am just asking... maybe you are right... In my opinion that is pointless

Comment: But OP _wants_ to loop through all results. (Whether it be to output an individual error message for every empty field, as the original code suggests, or for some other purpose …)

Answer (score 3):

```
function check_empty($post_array){
    $items_in_array = count($post_array); //array length
    echo $items_in_array;
    if($items_in_array < 1){
         echo 'no data submitted';
         return false;
    }
    $errors = '';
    foreach($post_array as $key=>$value){
        if(empty($value)){
            $errors.= $key . " field cannot be left empty" . "</br>";
        }
    }
    if($errors){
         echo $errors;
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Its not obvious what you are asking, but the above return false on the first empty value. If no empty values are discovered, the function will return true

Comment: Will this not return true if the post array is completely empty?

Comment: @steve if i return false inside foreach it will stop right on first iteration i want it to complete iteration and only stop when it has iterated over  all the values in that array($post_array)

Comment: @1to1k OK, i was not sure of that, i have ammended the answer to both return the values you expect, and echo out the errors

Answer (score 1):

To stop you can use either `break;` or `return;`

break if you want to stop for that itteration
return if you want to exit the loop and function compleatley.

Comment: You have probably meant `return` (not `exit`).

Answer (score 1):

```
function check_empty($post_array){
        $items_in_array = count($post_array); //array length
        echo $items_in_array;
        $rtVl = false
        foreach($post_array as $key=>$value){
            if(empty($value)){
                echo $key . " field cannot be left empty" . "</br>";
            }
            $rtVl = true;
        }
        return $rtVl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `break` or `return false` statement to exit from loop.

```
  foreach($post_array as $key=>$value){
        if(empty($value)){
            echo $key . " field cannot be left empty" . "</br>";
            break;//or return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i return false inside foreach it will stop right on first iteration i want it to complete iteration and only stop when it has iterated over  all the values in that array($post_array)

Comment: what about continue ? :It allows you to skip the execution of the rest of the iteration. It jumps immediately to the next iteration in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Return or Break; when your conditions are met.